# Custom 404 message when using PHP-FPM with Apache

Tags: php, apache, mod-fastcgi

I have Apache (2.2.22 on Debian) configured to handle PHP files via FastCGI:

> <FilesMatch ".+.php$">
>
> SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
>
> </FilesMatch>
>
> Action application/x-httpd-php /fcgi-bin/php5-fpm virtual Alias
>
> /fcgi-bin/php5-fpm /fcgi-bin-php5-fpm FastCgiExternalServer
>
> /fcgi-bin-php5-fpm -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 600
>   -pass-header Authorization

To show a custom File Not Found (HTTP 404) page is configured in Apache as follows:

> <Directory "/home/http/domain/root">
>
> ..
>
> ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound.htm
>
> ..
>
> </Directory>

Requests for **non-existing non-PHP files** are answered with the custom 404 pagenotfound.htm file. No problem.

But requests for **non-existing PHP files** are answered with http-status-header "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" and contents "File not found.", so not my custom error page. Problem!

The Apache error log shows (in the latter case):

> [Sat Nov 21 14:03:07 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx] FastCGI: server "/fcgi-bin-php5-fpm" stderr: Primary script unknown

How can I configure a custom 404 page for non-existing PHP files when using PHP-FPM?

Answer (score 9):

set "ProxyErrorOverride on" in either your global server config or in individual virtual hosts, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride

Comment: Unfortunately, this option is available in version 2.3.10 and later and the system in question runs version 2.2.

Comment: not according to the 2.2 documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2//mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride

Comment: Works on Apache 2.4

Answer (score 4):

When 'File not found' is shown instead of custom error page for non-existing .php files (and all other non-existing files get the correct custom error page)...

Centos 8, PHP 7.2.11
File: /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

Add 'ProxyErrorOverride On' after the SetHandler

```
<FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    ProxyErrorOverride On
</FilesMatch>
```

Not sure if required, but I then did:

```
    systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: You only need "systemctl reload apache2" (not restart)

Answer (score 1):

#### Option: ProxyErrorOverride

[`ProxyErrorOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride) can be used if you have access to the server's configuration. But it doesn't work within the `.htaccess` context and it will prevent PHP from outputting dynamic response bodies for all configured status codes (default: `400` to `599`).

#### Option: <If> directive (Apache 2.4+)

Let Apache check if the file exists, before invoking PHP:

```
<Files "*.php">
    <If "-e %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        # Assuming PHP-FPM over Unix socket via mod_proxy_fcgi.
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/path/to/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://
    </If>
    <Else>
        # Ensure that *.php files are never handled by the default handler.
        Redirect 404
    </Else>
</Files>
```

Docs: [<If>](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if), [Expression parser](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html), [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

#### Option: mod_rewrite

The `ErrorDocument` can be triggered using [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "\.php$" - [R=404]
```

Note: This only works if `REQUEST_FILENAME` has already been determined (so not in the *server config* or *virtual host*, but in a *directory* or *.htaccess* context). Otherwise it is equal to `REQUEST_URI` and that probably wouldn't be an existing local file.

Comment: This worked for me without needing access conf